# "A setup package is either missing or damaged visual studio 2015" while updating the VS2015 to fix the error when I try to publish my system

Tags: visual-studio

I encounter this error while publishing my system so i decided to fix it by following the tutorials on how to fix this error:
[image: I encounter this error while publishing my system so i decided to fix it by following the tutorials on how to fix this error]

and then this happened.:
[image: and then this happened.]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a common problem and there are several solutions on SO or Google.

https://youtu.be/ZCf5QKTPlMA

1. Open `Programs and Features`
2. Select `Microsoft Visual Studio 2015` and click `Change`
3. Press `Modify` to progress to `Features` options
4. Select `Windows and Web Development`, then tick `ClickOnce Publishing Tools` for installation
5. Then `Next` and then `Update`

[image: install screenshot]

This is what Microsoft recommends:

1. Go to Control Panel-Programs and Features, right click the VS 2015 and Change-Modify, confirm the option “ClickOnce Publishing Tools” is selected or not, if not, please select it to update
2. Right click the project name and choose Properties-Signing and uncheck the “Sign the ClickOnce manifests”

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/500d196e-6a25-46b7-b8da-4034b97a32be/signtoolexe-not-found?forum=visualstudiogeneral